# Nested looping with an associative array of arrays, getting no output (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Thanks in advance for looking.

I am trying to build some HTML using a foreach loop with a few layers of arrays.

Groups of data and groups of titles for that data are stored in sets of arrays.
In turn, those arrays of data are stored in an array (`$titlegroups` and `datagroups`).

The aim being to set up a nested loop, where each group of data and titles populate the relevant fields in some html.

Here is a full set of code (structure) of my attempt.

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;


$titlesA=array('string1','string2');
$titlesB=array('string3','string4');

$dataA=array($a,$b);
$dataB=array($c,$d);

$titlegroups=array($titlesA,$titlesB);
$datagroups=array($dataA,$dataB);
$groups=array(array_combine($titlegroups, $datagroups));

$j=0;   
foreach($groups as $titlesX => $dataX)
    {
        $j++;
        echo'<div class="something">';

        $i=0;
        foreach(array_combine($titlesX, $dataX) as $title => $var)
            {
            $i++;
            echo '
                    <li>'.$title.'</li><input name="'.$j.'x'.$i.'" value="'.$var.'" />
                ';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Checking it in ideone I get the error:

> Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer
>   given in /home/0zw0mb/prog.php on line 26

Line 26 is:

```
foreach(array_combine($titlesX, $dataX) as $title => $var)
```

but $titlesX and $dataX should both be arrays?

If anyone can set me straight I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: At least you identified yourself. I can see your (late) anger, but not the motivation. But this is a free speech site anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have arrays as keys, they are converted to strings. You logic required some changes and an additional sentinel variable (`$idx`), to tell when the code crosses one group to another.

`array_merge` was necessary due to the key requirements of arrays.

Check the below code:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;


$titlesA=array('string1','string2');
$titlesB=array('string3','string4');

$dataA=array($a,$b);
$dataB=array($c,$d);

$titlegroups=array_merge($titlesA,$titlesB);
$datagroups=array_merge($dataA,$dataB);

$items=array_combine($titlegroups, $datagroups);

$indexes = array(count($dataA), count($dataB));

$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$idx = $indexes[$j];

echo '<div class="something">';

foreach($items as $title => $var)
    {
            echo '
                    <li>'.$title.'</li><input name="'.$j.'x'.($i++).'" value="'.$var.'" />
                ';
        $idx--;

        if ($idx == 0) {
            /* End of a group */
            echo '</div>';
            $idx = $indexes[++$j];

            /* If there is another group, create new container */
            if ($idx != null) {
                echo '<div class="something">';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - I've made this adjustment but it doesn't seem to fix the central issue.

Comment: Ah your edit explains things very well, thank you. I'll study this and make the changes.

Comment: Hi. Working on a solution to the original problem with minimal code changes brought a learning topic: array keys (fed to `array_combine`) have requirements (can't be arrays). Even with a **working** code not so "readable" we learned something.